# How can I install Skype in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation, skype

I have tried many times, but I could not complete the process.

Comment: Tried how exactly? Please be detailed. Did you clean up after failed attempts?

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 17.04 and I just downloaded Skype and it worked. 
These are the steps I took.

**Part 1-Download**

1. Go to https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/ .
2. Wait for the options to populate, they should be the following.

   - Get Skype for Linux DEB
   - Get Skype for Linux RPM
   - Get Skype for Windows
   - Get Skype for Mac
3. Select Get Skype for Linux DEB. (Note: DEB refers to package type not distro. Ubuntu uses DEB packages.)
4. Download from the popup window.

**Part 2- Install**

1. Open Terminal
2. Go to directory of the package, or `cd Downloads/`
3. Type `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`
4. Type your password. Program should begin to install.

**Part 3-Test/ Open Skype**

1. Click Ubuntu search icon and type Skype.
2. Click Skype icon and you should be all set.